# Usercontrol with sizable tool window

Tags: c#, user-controls, border

In C# WinForms I'd like to make a UserControl that mimics the look of a ToolWindow -- sizable, with room for a caption and a close button at the top right. This seems possible through overriding CreateParams(), using the relevant constants from WinUser.h, and adding custom handlers for the appropriate mouse events, but it seems like a lot of trouble for something that simple. Before I go to it, is there an easier way?

Comment: Hey Aaron, maybe i'm just not understanding your question. What is going to be in this UserControl??

Comment: A grid as it happens, but my idea is to define a class deriving from UserControl in which I can implement a border of this kind, and then stick whatever content I please inside of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really rather the easiest way is to just use a Form with FormBorderStyle = SizeableToolWindow.  That's what it was made for.  Display it with the Show(owner) overload so it is always on top of your main window.  If you want to salvage the UserControl then just Dock = Fill in the form.  Albeit that exposing its properties get harder to do cleanly.

Check out Weifenluo's DockPanel Suite for a windowing model that resembles Visual Studio's.

Comment: Thanks Hans. In combination with SetParent() and ShowWindow() from the API, this gives me the behavior I need. The ToolWindows stay within the form and I get the border and caption for free.

Comment: Hackorama.  Just set the TopLevel property to false if you want to do this.

Comment: Oh I agree. I didn't know about TopLevel and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

ToolWindow is a window, UserControl is a control that sits INSIDE a window (like a text box, button, etc.). If you want to have a UserControl that is sizable and has a caption and a close button, I think you'll have to create a caption bar and close button and size grips as parts of the control itself.

You'd need to remove the control from its parent on "close", and resize the control in its parent on "resizing" with size grips.